# Is this a safe way to filter data and prevent SQL-injection and other attacks?

Tags: php, sql, function, code-injection

I created two simple functions to filter inserted data before it's entered into a mysql query.

For formfields (I am also using regular expressions to check each field individually.

```
// Form filter
function filter($var) 
{               

    // HTML is not allowed
    $var = strip_tags(trim($var)); 

    // Check magic quotes and stripslashes
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    { 
        $var = stripslashes($var);
}

    // Not using it right now, is it recommended?
    // $var = htmlentities($var, ENT_QUOTES);

    // Escape
    $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);

    // Return    
    return $var; 
}
```

Then for id's (sent in the URL) I am using this filter:

```
// ID filter
function idfilter($idfilter)
{
// Delete everything except numbers
$idfilter = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $idfilter);

// Round numbers
$idfilter = round($idfilter);

// Test if the input is indeed a number
if(!is_numeric($idfilter) || $idfilter % 1 != 0)
{
    $idfilter = 0;
}

// Filter using the formfilter (above)
return filter($idfilter);
}
```

Are there suggestions to add or strip from these simple functions? And is it "safe"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using deprecated function as `magic_quotes` and `ereg_*`. To prevent Sql injection you should use **prepared statement** (I suggest to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) and to prevent XSS you should use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) as you're doing.

Comment: +1, but maybe using [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) is more appropriate when you've content like HTML code that should be visible and not interpreted and of course should not be stripped.

Comment: As mentioned, dump `ereg_*` in favor of `preg_*` for any regex work.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameters in your queries instead of concatenating string.

Filters and cleaners are usually not safe enough.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with your first line.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1):

If you are using integer ids `idFilter()` can be safely stripped down to

```
function idfilter($idfilter) {
  return (int)$idfilter;
}
```

As others have suggested, using parametrized queries is the right way to go though.