# Filter HTML on php

Tags: php, html, validation, security

On my client side, I have a rich text area where the user is allowed to enter HTML. Then, how on PHP do i ensure that the PHP is safe. Is there any validation in php for checking HTML??

from safe I mean that the HTML does not contain any malicious code

Comment: The question is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512712/sanitizing-html-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to **sanitize your input** before saving it. http://htmlpurifier.org/ does a great job and is pretty easy to implement and insanely configurable.

Comment: Yep, agree. HtmlPurifier has been commonly referenced as doing sanitizing best! http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html contains a very large list of possible XSS attacks. You will never be able to counter those by hand...!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into HTMLPurifier http://htmlpurifier.org/, I have yet to use it but I remember seeing a screencast or two on it at www.zendcasts.com.

You could also use a Zend Framework Filter like Zend_Filter_StripTags.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the tags that are not allowed, using strip_tags();

```
<?php
$allow = '<p><ul><li><b><strong>'; // Just an example
$input = strip_tags($input,$allowedtags);
?>
```

Other than that it's adviced to use  mysql_real_escape_string($input) or better yet, use: [Is this a safe way to filter data and prevent SQL-injection and other attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413412/is-this-a-safe-way-to-filter-data-and-prevent-sql-injection-and-other-attacks)

Comment: you should point out clearly that html filtering and sql escaping are different countermeasures for different attack vendors:  SQL injection (which breaks your DB) vs PHP/HTML injection (which breaks your application / website)

Comment: Agreed, it are two different things. But since the TS spoke about "malicious code" i thought i'd add it.